# Error while inserting data in mongodb with pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am new to pymongo and mongodb. I am trying to insert documents interactively with pymongo. When I am trying the document via a python script, it's failing.

Enter the name:
test3

Enter the address: Someaddress

Enter the phone number: 9876543

```
{"Name": "test3", "Phone": 9876543, "Address": "Someaddress"} # Here I am printing the document to be inserted

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./sample.py", line 54, in <module>
insertDocument()

 File "./sample.py", line 27, in insertDocument

 insert_id=db.collection.insert_one(obj)

 File "/appl/swinstall/mongo-python-driver-master/pymongo/collection.py", line 676, in insert_one

common.validate_is_document_type("document", document)

 File "/appl/swinstall/mongo-python-driver-master/pymongo/common.py", line 434, in validate_is_document_type

"collections.MutableMapping" % (option,))

TypeError: document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, bson.raw_bson.RawBSONDocument, or a type that inherits from collections.MutableMapping
```

Below is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import os
from pymongo import MongoClient
ch=MongoClient()
db=ch.local

def insertDocument():
print "insertDocument"
print "Enter the name:"
name=raw_input(">> ")
print "Enter the address"
address=raw_input(">> ")
print "Enter the phone number"
phone=raw_input(">> ")
obj='{"Name": "'+ str(name) +'", "Phone": '+ str(phone) +', "Address": "'+ str(address) +'"}'
print obj
insert_id=db.collection.insert_one(obj)

insertDocument()
```

But when I am trying the same in python terminal, it's getting inserted.

```
test={"Name":"Test3", "Phone":98765653, "Address":"SomeAddress"}

insert_id=db.collection.insert_one(test)

x=db.collection.find()

x.count()

5

for y in x:

... print y

...

{u'Phone': 123456, u'_id': ObjectId('5ac59b23788b851887bb4a77'), u'Name': u'test', u'Address': u'DHL'}
{u'Phone': 5678990, u'_id': ObjectId('5ac5be03788b851c9f7da382'), u'Name': u'test2', u'Address': u'Cyberjaya'}
{u'Phone': 7872476, u'_id': ObjectId('5ac5be3b788b851c9f7da383'), u'Name': u'test3', u'Address': u'Kuala Lumpur'}
{u'Phone': 8977101750L, u'_id': ObjectId('5ac5dc59788b8523141b43eb'), u'Name': u'Soumya', u'Address': u'Cybersquare'}
{u'Phone': 98765653, u'_id': ObjectId('5acace4a788b855f05c7ea0d'), u'Name': u'Test3', u'Address': u'SomeAddress'} <== This got inserted
```

Can someone help?

Comment: `db.collection.insert_one('obj')` You are passing string `obj` to be inserted. Insert argument must be a `dict`. Remove the quotes around `obj`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Removed the single quote. Still error.

{"Name": "test4", "Phone": 9864362, "Address": "someaddr"}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./sample.py", line 54, in <module>
    insertDocument()
  File "./sample.py", line 27, in insertDocument
    `insert_id=db.collection.insert_one(obj)`
  File "/appl/swinstall/mongo-python-driver-master/pymongo/collection.py", line 676, in insert_one
    common.validate_is_document_type("document", document)
  File "/appl/swinstall/mongo-python-driver-master/pymongo/common.py", line 434, in validate_is_document_type...

Comment: `obj` value is string, it should be `dict`!

Comment: `obj='...'` # here lies the problem

Answer (score 0):

**Change your code by this:**

`insert_id=db.collection.insert_one(json.loads(obj))`

Answer (score 0):

The error message gives a hint. It says that obj must be a dict. In the interactive method you are indeed defining a dict, but in the script you are creating a string. The string looks like a dict, but it is not.

You can confirm this by printing:

> print (type(obj))

So, the solution is to store it in a dict, with key value pairs. Something like:

> obj = {}
>
> obj["name"]=str(name)
>
> etc....